# Problems with animate Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

**JS nothing interesting:**

```
 $( "#scroll-left" ).click(function() {
        $( "#pics-scroll" ).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
        });

        $( "#scroll-right" ).click(function() {
        $( "#pics-scroll" ).animate({ "right": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
        });
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="new-products" class="clear-fix">
<button id="scroll-left"></button>
<div id="pics-scroll">
<img src="upload/upd_img_1.png" alt="Обувь">
<img src="upload/upd_img_2.png" alt="Обувь">
<img src="upload/upd_img_3.png" alt="Обувь">
<img src="upload/upd_img_1.png" alt="Обувь">
</div>
<button id="scroll-right"></button>
</div>
```

My CSS is here (nothing interesting too ):

```
#new-products{
        height: 169px;
        position: relative;
        padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }

    #new-products img {
        float: left;
        height: 169px;
        width: 170px;
        background: #ffffff;
        width: 170px;
        height: 169px;
        margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    }

    #pics-scroll{
        position: absolute;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 169px;
        margin-left:85px;
    }

    #scroll-left{
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 50px 5px 0 13px;
        width: 54px;
        height: 70px;
        display: block;
        background: url('../images/scroll-left.png')center no-repeat;
    }

    #scroll-right{
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: 840px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 50px;
        width: 54px;
        height: 70px;
        display: block;
        background: url('../images/scroll-right.png')center no-repeat;
    }
```

The main problem is : it doesn't move anyway.

I don't know, why it doesn't work. How can i make it work.

Comment: your jquery code is wrong. You need to wrap it inside function that will fire on load or readiness like $(document).ready(function() {...} );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your code inside `$(window).load(function() {...});` to make sure all of your DOM elements and images have been loaded properly before executing your jQuery code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#scroll-left").click(function () {
        $("#pics-scroll").animate({
            "left": "+=50px"
        }, "slow");
    });

    $("#scroll-right").click(function () {
        $("#pics-scroll").animate({
            "right": "+=50px"
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is a real epic fail :D